# How can you test two datasets to determine if they originate from the same generating process?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, data-mining, two-sample

I have two feature matrices X_i and X_j, with identical features but their own n - is there a statistical test to determine if the latent data generating process behind X_i is indistinguishable from the latent data generating process behind X_j?

Slightly longer way to frame the problem: say you have two CSVs - they have the same columns, but different rows of observations. What I'd like to know is if there is a principled way for one to conclude that the rows from the first CSV look sufficiently different from the second CSV such that we can reasonably claim that the sampled rows in the first CSV originated from a different source as compared to the second CSV. If you used an SVM / machine learner approach for example, you could maybe say that "if all rows from the first CSV are linearly separable from the second CSV, then we can conclude that there is at least some distinguishing path through the datasets such that all observations can be binned correctly". I don't believe that there's a "correct" answer here, because we never truly know the ground truth, but this is more about how one would go about making a convincing argument about the degree to which two sampled CSVs cover the same sampled space.

Answer (score 2):

This is called [two-sample testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-sample_hypothesis_testing) ([two-sample](/questions/tagged/two-sample)). Approaches include:

- If your data is one-dimensional, the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).
- If your data can be reasonably modeled to be normally distributed, a [$t$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution#Two-sample_statistic).
- More generally, there are two main approaches:

  - The [maximum mean discrepancy](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume13/gretton12a/gretton12a.pdf) or the ([equivalent](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1383661264)) [distance correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation) give tests based on an assumed similarity/distance between points; you can also [optimize the underlying similarity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.04488).
  - [Classifier-based](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.06545) tests train a classifier to distinguish the two sets (on a "training set"), and then look at their accuracy (on a "test set") to construct a hypothesis test.

Comment: The data is, by any regular reading of the definition of the problem, not one-dimensional, and no assumption of normality of distribution can be made here, so KS-test and t-test are out. The MMD approach seems more likely to yield results here. In general, however, I don't think this falls under the common framing of a two-sample test.

Comment: If your problem isn't exactly a standard two-sample test, then I've totally misunderstood your question statement, and the "unclear what you're asking" hold reason is accurate. You should clarify your question, maybe by adding a simple example of the kind of thing you mean.

Comment: Edited above with slightly clearer (hopefully) more grounded explanation.

Comment: This still sounds exactly like a two-sample test to me: your first dataset is a sample from some unknown distribution $\mathbb P$, your second from an unknown distribution $\mathbb Q$, and the question is whether you can confidently say $\mathbb P \ne \mathbb Q$ given the particular sample datasets. Your SVM example is related to a classifier two-sample test.